# Addind values over loop in FOP with XSL and XML

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have this XML and XSL example:

XML:

```
<mastercount>
  <sourceval>
    <attm>50</attm>
    <fh>6500</fh>
    <id>1</id>
  </sourceval>
  <sourceval>
    <attm>15</attm>
    <fh>2300</fh>
    <id>2</id>
  </sourceval>
  <sourceval>
    <attm>4</attm>
    <fh>280</fh>
    <id>3</id>
  </sourceval>
  <sourceval>
    <attm>20</attm>
    <fh>2700</fh>
    <id>4</id>
  </sourceval>
</mastercount>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:variable name="var_idx">
  <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="var_sum_attm" />
<xsl:variable name="var_sum_fh" />
<fo:table-row>
    <xsl:for-each select="/mastercount">
        <fo:table-cell padding="3pt" border-style="solid" width="12mm" border-width="1pt" text-align="right">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="sourceval[position()=$var_idx]/attm" />               
            </fo:block>     
        </fo:table-cell>

        <fo:table-cell padding="3pt" border-style="solid" width="12mm" border-width="1pt" text-align="right">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="sourceval[position()=$var_idx]/fh" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:for-each>
</fo:table-row>
```

This part of the source works great and I get

```
         attm  fh   attm    fh
 Val2     50 6500    0    6500 
 Val1     15 2300    0    2300 
 Val3    280    0  280       0 
 Val4     20 2700    0    2700
```

(I skipped the name part above in the source)

However I now need a sum of those 2 fields:

```
         attm  fh   attm    fh
 Val2     50 6500    0    6500 
 Val1     15 2300    0    2300 
 Val3    280    0  280       0 
 Val4     20 2700    0    2700
        sum   sum  sum     sum
```

How can I get this to work?

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.
TheVagabond

UPDATE:

Thanks to RT72 here is an answer:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/mastercount">
    <fo:table-cell padding="3pt" border-style="solid" width="12mm" border-width="1pt" text-align="right">
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(sourceval/attm)"/>                                            
      </fo:block>                                       
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell padding="3pt" border-style="solid" width="12mm" border-width="1pt" text-align="right">
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(sourceval/fh)" />
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
 <xsl:variable name="var_sum_attm" select="sum(/mastercount/sourceval/attm)"/>
 <xsl:variable name="var_sum_fh" select="sum(/mastercount/sourceval/fh)"/>
```

**Updated after OP edited question**

try this

```
<xsl:for-each select="/mastercount/sourceval">
<fo:table-row>                              
    <fo:table-cell padding="3pt" border-style="solid" width="12mm" border-width="1pt" text-align="right"> 
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="attm" />
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell padding="3pt" border-style="solid" width="12mm" border-width="1pt" text-align="right"> 
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="fh" />
         </fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

```
<fo:table-row>                              
<fo:table-cell padding="3pt" border-style="solid" width="12mm" border-width="1pt" text-align="right"> 
    <fo:block>
         <xsl:value-of select="sum(/mastercount/sourceval/attm)" />
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding="3pt" border-style="solid" width="12mm" border-width="1pt" text-align="right"> 
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(/mastercount/sourceval/fh)" />
     </fo:block>
 </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Comment: see my edited answer along lines of sum(/mastercount/sourceval/attm). This will give you full totals

Comment: I doesn't show the sum for some reason, the tablefields are there and correct but they are empty

Comment: you need to put the variable declarations outside your for-each

Comment: I works but it takes the first numbers adds them and uses them always. It sould add the numbers of each column and use them only there

Comment: @Thevagabond fyi you don't need the for-each around the total since you have accessed all the node info you need - you might want to take a look at my latest update as it gives what  IMHO is a more efficient solution for both the detail rows and the summary row, the position stuff and var_idx variable you are using is not necessary I think

Answer (score 1):

It can be simpler to use `xsl:template`s that reflect the structure of your source and let the XSLT processor work out what to process.  The example below does the summing in the template for `mastercount`, and the templates for `sourceval` and both `attm` and `fh` generate their respective FOs:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="table-cell">
    <xsl:attribute name="padding">3pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="width">12mm</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-width">1pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">right</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:template match="mastercount">
    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-cell">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(sourceval/attm)" />
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-cell">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(sourceval/fh)" />
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sourceval">
    <fo:table-row>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="attm | fh"/>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attm | fh">
    <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-cell">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
```

If you wanted to only have one template that generates an `fo:table-cell` with your desired properties, you could change the templates for `mastercount` and `attm` and `fh` to:

```
<xsl:template match="mastercount">
    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <fo:table-row>
                <xsl:call-template name="table-cell">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="sum(sourceval/attm)" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="table-cell">
                    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="sum(sourceval/fh)" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attm | fh" name="table-cell">
    <xsl:param name="value" select="." />

    <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-cell">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this

```
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(for $i in //attm return $i)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(for $i in //fh return $i)"/>
```

Comment: I get an error that ,, it expected but $ is been found and how do I get the $i outside the loop, since I need the sum row after the table not after every row?

Comment: you can call this value from out of the table, and just change xpath //attm to mastercount/sourceval/attm